# Vuejs axios count results after they have been returned

Tags: vuejs2, axios

I'm trying to find the correct way to get the number of returned results from my async `axios` get query but not getting anywhere so hoping someone can assist

My code is as follows

```
mounted() {
      axios.get('http')
      .then(response => {
        this.myItems = response.data // this works
        countResults(response) //this doesn't seem to
      .catch(error => console.log(error))
      })
    },

    filters:{
        countResults: function(value){
            return value.length;
    }
```

I then call as follows

```
<p>Number of Entries: {{countResults}}</p>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can call the filter method in this way

```
this.$options.filters.countResults(response)
```

To solve your problem you need to store the response. You can do that in this way

```
mounted() {
  axios.get('http')
    .then(response => {
       this.myItems = response.data // this works
       this.responseData = response.data
     }).catch(error => console.log(error))
},

data: {
    responseData: []
},

filters: {
  countResults: function(){
  return this.responseData.length;
}
```

Comment: Many Thanks but still getting 0 results when there are 4 records being returned... Is this bit correct? <p>Number of Entries: {{countResults}}</p>

Comment: You'll not get the actual result because your approach is not correct

Comment: Ok thanks, can you point me ay anything to help me take the correct approach please or give an example

Comment: Thanks, so where do I use this.$options.filters.countResults(response), sorry newbe and learning but still confused and still get 0 results

Comment: It is not necessary to use

Comment: I get [Vue warn]: Property or method "countResults" is not defined, I've been reading but no idea why as I've followed what you have written exactly and its all in the same component? my code is exactly as you kindly covered above and calling by <p>Number of Entries: {{countResults}}</p>